# JSON missing Double Quotes iOS

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, afnetworking-2

I'm encountering a weird problem. I am parsing json data from our server. when I access it via my browser it shows this data:

```
productCombinationAttributes": [
    {
      "value": "Green",
      "price": "0",
      "img_id": "1005",
      "name": "color",
      "id": "b_9"
    },
    {
      "value": "Blue",
      "price": "0",
      "img_id": "1005",
      "name": "color",
      "id": "b_10"
    },
    {
      "value": "Yellow",
      "price": "0",
      "img_id": "1005",
      "name": "color",
      "id": "b_14"
    },
    {
      "value": "Xl",
      "price": "100",
      "img_id": "1005",
      "name": "size",
      "id": "b_11"
    },
    {
      "value": "L",
      "price": "50",
      "img_id": "1005",
      "name": "size",
      "id": "b_12"
    },
    {
      "value": "Metal",
      "price": "0.00",
      "img_id": "1005",
      "name": "material",
      "id": "b_13"
    }
  ],
  "productSpecification": [],
  "paymentMethod": [
    "Credit or Debit Card",
    "Paypal",
    "Dragon Pay",
    "Cash on Delivery"
  ],
  "productCombinatiobDetails": [
    {
      "quantity": "12",
      "combinationId": [
        "b_9",
        "b_12",
        "b_13"
      ],
      "id": 1519,
      "location": {
        "NCR": "100.0000",
        "Makati": "120.0000"
      }
    },
    {
      "quantity": "12",
      "combinationId": [
        "b_14",
        "b_11",
        "b_13"
      ],
      "id": 1520,
      "location": {
        "NCR": "100.0000",
        "Makati": "120.0000"
      }
    }
  ]
```

But when I access it via XCODE and parse it using afnetworking or other methods of parsing it. JSON looks like this:

```
productCombinationAttributes =     (
                {
            id = "b_9";
            "img_id" = 1005;
            name = color;
            price = 0;
            value = Green;
        },
                {
            id = "b_10";
            "img_id" = 1005;
            name = color;
            price = 0;
            value = Blue;
        },
                {
            id = "b_14";
            "img_id" = 1005;
            name = color;
            price = 0;
            value = Yellow;
        },
                {
            id = "b_11";
            "img_id" = 1005;
            name = size;
            price = 100;
            value = Xl;
        },
                {
            id = "b_12";
            "img_id" = 1005;
            name = size;
            price = 50;
            value = L;
        },
                {
            id = "b_13";
            "img_id" = 1005;
            name = material;
            price = "0.00";
            value = Metal;
        }
    );
```

Here's my code on parsing it:

```
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"url.com"] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
        [self jsonParser:parentView scrollView:sv_parent];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure");
    }];
```

The problem is the double quotes are missing after i display the return data upon after my request. Can someone help me with this? thank you in advance :)

Comment: because you are displaying the object in JSOM format, it just how NSDictionary display things

Comment: Ahh so I need to convert it to string?

Comment: What you see is how NSLog displays NSArrays and NSDictionarys.  You cannot transmit that format as JSON, you must use NSJSONSerialization to convert it to a JSON string.  (But, of course, if you're trying to access the data in the JSON, you just access it from the arrays/dictionarys.)

Comment: that's not likely, what are you trying to do with them? AFNetworking kindly parse the JSON string for you and you want discard their hard work?

Comment: Because I need to get the json data and convert it to string and send it again to the server with some additional strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not missing. Your print is `[NSDictionary description]` not a json string. 
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager already parsed json to `NSDictionary` for you. 
If you want to get origin json string, you can use `[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]` to serialize NSDictionary to json string.

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject options:0 error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: How can I implement [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]?

Comment: If you want to access the original JSON as a string, AFNetworking provides that as `operation.responseString`.

Comment: In the dicrionary description: Why is id without quotes and "img_id" with quotes?